# Universal Image Loader - Image URL 404 Error handling

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, universal-image-loader

I am trying to use the Android Universal Image Loader library to download images from a URL from the web. However, the URLs can return a 404 error because the picture sometimes hasn't been uploaded by the company. How do I handle this? I tried using the following but it had no effect:

```
DisplayImageOoptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
  .cacheInMemory()
  .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image)
  .build();
```

Can someone please help me out and point me in the right direction? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: How are you getting the URL if the image doesn't exist?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use:

```
DisplayImageOoptions options = new    DisplayImageOptions.Builder().
cacheInMemory().
showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image).
showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image).
build();
```

Comment: showImageOnFail - Perfect, thank you so much! worked like a charm :)

Comment: wish I could vote you but I don't have the reputation point required :)

Comment: Sorry I just saw that I never accepted the answer! Again thank you so much shamimz