# Universal Image Loader - Not caching URL 404

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Based on this discussion:
[Universal Image Loader - Image URL 404 Error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189268/universal-image-loader-image-url-404-error-handling)

I make Image Loader. It is work FINE!
But in my case the image files deleted on the server by expired. I would like that the cached query URL 404 for this, but is not cached, and happens every time when i scroll down the listview in this pending image URL for get 404. How does it cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very late answer, but it will help others, the answer is simply explain here,

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false).delayBeforeLoading(10)
            .showImageOnFail(null).showImageForEmptyUri(null) // this will intitate null if there is loading fail or empty url
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).handler(new Handler())
            .build();
```

And Handle 404 using this

```
    ImgLoader.displayImage(Globals.Image_Domain + largeimageUrl,
                largeImage, Base.options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // This will handle 404 and it will catch null exception
                        // do here what you want to do 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (largeImage == null)
                            return;

                        largeImage.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                            View view) {
                    }

                });
```

Comment: In what sense is this a solution? What to do onLoadingFailed so it will be cached?

Comment: In that case  you should use `.showImageOnFail(anydrawable).showImageForEmptyUri(anydrawable)`

Comment: I have set that but it still tries to reload the image from the url the next time.